# How can I make the lines thicker?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

Came up with this and wanted to see if I could make the halos thicker and more substanced. I'm using a material to get this effect.[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean wider radially, or thicker up-down?

Comment: I mean thicker in all directions

Comment: Without going into volumetric shaders, which could  be fuzzy/expensive, it might be better to create geometry to do that? It depends on your desired overall effect.